# react native setState inside an async asyncStorage function

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-hooks, asyncstorage, expo-auth-session

I am using the `expo-auth-session` package to make a request to the Spotify API to get access tokens, then saving to `AsyncStorage`.

A `save` function that stores the token in `AsyncStorage`:

```js
const save = async (token) => {
    try{
        AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

A `getItem` function that gets the access token value from `AsyncStorage`, and sets that value to the `spotifyAccessToken` state

```js
const [spotifyAccessToken, setSpotifyAccessToken] = useState('');
```

```js
const getItem =  async () => {
    try{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token')
        setSpotifyAccessToken(token);
        
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Using the `useAuthRequest` from `expo-auth-session` to make a request to Spotify API, the request code below works.

```js
 const discovery = {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
        tokenEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    };

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({
        // responseType: ResponseType.Token,
        responseType: 'code',
        clientId: client_id,
        //clientSecret: client_secret,
        scopes: ['user-read-recently-played'],
        usePKCE: false,
        redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
    }, discovery)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success'){
 
            //console.log(response.params.code);
            axios.request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    Authorization: `Basic ${new Buffer.from(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`).toString('base64')}`,
                },
                data: {
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                    code: response.params.code,
                    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI
                } 
            }).then(res => {
             
                save(res.data.access_token);
               
            }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
        }
    },
    [response]);
```

A button that triggers the user to login using Spotify account, after authenticating, it redirects back to this component screen, however, I want the text below the button to be displayed from "Loading..." to the `spotifyAccessToken` immediately after it redirects to the component screen, but it wouldn't. After I re-run my application, the token is displayed, which means it was successfully stored in `AsyncStorage`, but didn't update the state immediately. How can solve this? Thanks.

```js
const [spotifyAccessToken, setSpotifyAccessToken] = useState(null);




useEffect(()=>{
        //clearTokens();
        // console.log('storage: ' + getValueForfor('access_token'))
        // console.log('state: ' + spotifyAccessToken)
        getItem()
    }, [spotifyAccessToken])




<Button title='login to spotify' onPress={() => promptAsync()}/>
{spotifyAccessToken != '' ? <Text> {spotifyAccessToken} </Text> : <Text> Loading... </Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening if you are redirecting to the component with `getItem` too early: before the `AsyncStorage` is done saving the token. Due to this, at the initial render of the component(with `getItem`), `AsyncStorage.getItem` might be getting the old value of `access_token` and not the updated one.

To possibly fix this issue, try redirecting to the next component only after `AsyncStorage.setItem` promise is resolved completely. Something like this:

This is how your save function should look like: it should return a `Promise` value:

```js
const save = async (token) => {
    try{
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

And redirect to the next component after the `save` return promise value is resolved:

```js
...
).then(async (res) => {         
    await save(res.data.access_token);
    // Redirect here, after save is resolved
})...
```

---

Answering the question you asked in the comments to this answer:

> it's not working still, you said that the save function should return a promise value, where in the code should I put it

Using `await` for a `Promise` makes the function wait till the promise is resolved (here when `setItem` is done). You do not need to explicitly return a `Promise` value from the `async` function in this case. If you do not use `await`, the function will return prematurely (without waiting for the `setItem` promise). The  `setItem` promise will still resolve concurrently just that your code wouldn't be able to know when it is resolved.

By using `await` for `setItem` here, you just propagate promise resolution to the calling function(here in the `then(res => {...})` block).

In the `then(res => {})` block you can either use `await` to wait for the `save` to complete before executing the next statement. Or use `then/catch` and add the next statement to execute after `save` is done in the `then` block.

---

Edit: As OP mentioned in the comments below, the redirection to the next component is done automatically. Well, in this case, setting the value in `AsyncStorage` and immediately getting it in the next component might not work as expected because of the above-mentioned reason.

First, you will need to check if the auto-redirection to the next component is really done after the `axios` request completes or before it, i.e. as soon as `response?.type === 'success'`. I am unable to understand why you have made the `axios` request after you already got `success` from auth request

If the redirection is happening before the `axios` request call then you might be able to access the token in the `success` condition itself:

```js
if (response?.type === 'success'){
    // Check if the token is available here?
    console.debug(`Response = ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

    // If token is available here itself, then why is the axios request required? 
    // Save the token here itself...
    // Use SessionStorage if required, implementation explained below in the answer


    ...
}
```

---

If you confirmed the above and the auto-redirection is really done after the `axios` request and NOT after `response?.type === 'success'` then:

You could use [react-native-session-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-session-storage) as volatile storage to set and get the token in the *same session* and use `AsyncStorage` in parallel to it to set and get the token in/from persistent memory.

So, the `save` function will look like this with `SessionStorage`:

```js
import SessionStorage from 'react-native-session-storage';
...

const save = async (token) => {
    try{
        // Set token in SessionStorage as well to allow access to the value immediately
        SessionStorage.setItem(`access_token`, token);

        // Store token to AsyncStorage to persist it when the app closes.
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

And `getItem` function will look like this:

```js
import SessionStorage from 'react-native-session-storage';
...

const getItem =  async () => {
    try{
        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
        
        // If the token is not yet set in Async Storage, fetch it from Session Storage
        // If it's set in Async Storage, use that value
        if(!token) // If it's null
            token = SessionStorage.getItem('access_token');

        setSpotifyAccessToken(token);

        // Don't forget to clear both SessionStorage and AsyncStorage on logout!        
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

---

Why both storages?

**AsyncStorage**
-> to persist the token when the user re-opens the app.

**SessionStorage**
-> as an immediate way to R/W the value during the same session (gets cleared when the app closes).

Another solution:
Use [ContextProvider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider), if your code structure allows it. Wrap the context over the *next* component to "listen" to token value state change from anywhere in the children components.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping, I added async await when calling the save function, it's not working still, you said that the save function should return a promise value, where in the code should I put it? Also, the promptAsync method just automatically redirects back to the component screen that contains the button, I didn't put any code for it to redirect

Comment: @JaydenYu The auto-redirection might be a problem. I'd suggest you use this package to [react-native-session-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-session-storage) to allow accessing to the token immediately unlike `AsyncStorage`. I have edited the answer to include this solution.

Comment: Re-edited the answer to change the sequence of storage calls to prevent blocking `SessionStorage` from awaiting `AsyncStorage.setItem(...)` call.